# wso2(esb,bpel) with jboss - Management

Tags: jboss, wso2

my name is Alex and I would like of deploy wso2(esb,bpel) in jboss application server.

About this question, I need to manage about 15 machines with wso2 esb and jboss.

So how would the issue of a centralized manage? I ask this because I have experience with weblogic server application where there is the concept of (Domain, Cluster, managed 
machines) on a single vision to facilitating the administrator.

With the wso2 esb,bpel etc I can to install only standalone servers?

Regarding an upgrade for example I would have application on each server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to deploy WSO2 products on another application servers. You should be able to use the standalone products.

WSO2 products also support clustering and deployment synchronizer, so that you can just setup cluster quickly and use a Management node to synchronize artifacts among the worker nodes. This means that you can have the same application seamlessly synchronized in all servers.

For example, see:

- http://wso2.com/library/articles/introduction-wso2-carbon-clustering/
- http://wso2.com/library/articles/clustering-landscape-wso2-stack/
- http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB203/Setup+ELB+with+WSO2+ESB
- http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Configuring+Deployment+Synchronizer